# run cloud-init disk_setup module on every boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I have an ec2 instance with an ephemeral disk. This instance goes down every night and boots up when needed. I used cloud-init to format the ephemeral disk and this works correct but only once. 
when this machine is stopped and started (and the ephemeral disk disappears) it no longer runs this cloud-init module. I have attempted to override the default frequency by declaring the module in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg as

```
cloud_init_modules:
 - [ disk-setup, always ]
```

And I have tried changing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_disk_setup.py by changing the following variable

```
frequency = ALWAYS
```

Is it possible to force the module to run on every boot or do i need to approach this differently?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a minor typo in module name (dash in `disk-setup` is incorrect).  This works just fine for me:

```yaml
cloud_init_modules:
  [disk_setup, always]
```

Here's a [relevant excerpt from the docs](https://github.com/cloud-init/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt#L176):

```
# cloud_config_modules:
# This is an array of arrays or strings.
# if item is a string, then it is read as a module name
# if the item is an array it is of the form:
#   name, frequency, arguments
# where 'frequency' is one of:
#   once-per-instance
#   always
```

It seems there's no way to set *frequency* in module configuration section.